# Windows Security message pops up when trying to access Parse in my Facebook Unity game

Tags: unity-game-engine

Since I upgraded to Unity 5 I'm having a HUGE problem. You see, I'm making a facebook game and I'm using Parse to save all the players data. The game was working well until I decided to upgrade to Unity 5... the weird thing is that it works perfectly in the Editor but when I build my game and upload it to facebook and play it from the canvas I get this message:

[image: Windows Security popup]

(The pop up window says in Spanish: "WINDOWS SECURITY - THE SERVER API.PARSE.COM REQUIRES A USERNAME AND A PASSWORD")

I know this line of code is the one causing this problem because the message pops up the moment this line is supposed to execute:

```
IEnumerator LoginToParse()

    {   ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(FB.UserId, FB.AccessToken, DateTime.Now);

           ........
```

If I close up that pop up message (which, by the way, I have to do so three times!) my game continues like normal but without any saving to Parse or loading from Parse capabilities.

I'm pretty sure this is a Unity 5 error that I'm not seeing anyone on the web talking about, because when I re-built the game in Unity 4.6 no window appeared and the game worked perfectly.

Any good insight or help about this problem will be greatly appreciated.